# Simple code to connect to MongoDB with NodeJS not executed

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When I run the code below, that I have copy/pasted directly from https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";  

console.log("Start");

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {

    console.log("inside");
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("bouquin");
    dbo.collection("products").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result.name);
      db.close();
    });
  });

  console.log("End");
```

Then console will display "Start" , "End" but not "inside". It seems the `MongoClient.connect` is not called.

But when I run this code, it works (please note that the URI is the same, not this issue is *not* a credential issue).

```
async function listDatabases(client){
    databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();

    console.log("Databases:");
    databasesList.databases.forEach(db => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
};

async function main(){
    

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();

        // Make the appropriate DB calls
        await  listDatabases(client);

       // var collections = client.db("bouquin").listCollections();

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Any clue?

Comment: `MongoClient.connect` is an asynchronous function, so "End" should be printed before it's callback is called.

Comment: `MongoClient.connect` does not accept a callback anymore in newer versions. Thats why your "inside" is not printed. Also notice the comment from Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with calling an asynchronous function, but not waiting for the result, and your code is 'procedural'.

What you do here is:

1. Print "Start"
2. Attempt to connect to database
3. Print "End"

Connecting to database takes time, and since you didn't wait for your response, nodejs executed your code and finished.

What you could've done is used either Promises or Async/Await:

**Option 1.**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 
const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

console.log("Start");

MongoClient.connect(uri)
.then(mongoClient => {
    console.log(mongoClient)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})

console.log("End")
```

This would result in printing "Start", "End", then mongoClient object (you didn't wait for it), but it is printed asynchronously, once it established a connection.
[image]

**Option 2.**

Promise inside an asynchronous function:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

(async () => {
    console.log("Start");
    
    await MongoClient.connect(uri)
    .then(mongoClient => {
        console.log(mongoClient)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    console.log("End")
})()
```

**Option 3: Async/Await**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";

(async () => {
    console.log("Start");
    
    try {
        const mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(uri)
        console.log(mongoClient)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    console.log("End")
})()
```

Bear in mind that both Option2 and Option3 will give the same result - "Start", mongoClient object, "End", because you await for the result.

[image]

Comment: It works ! Thanks you for your clear and full detailed answer !